# Google AMP Accelerated Mobile Pages in Jekyll amplify template

Tags: amp-html

I would like to take advantage of Google's Accelerated Mobile Pages:
https://www.ampproject.org/ describing https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml

ICYMI, it replaces some HTML tags with Google's to deliver pages super-fast.

More specifically, I'd like to see how to make Jekyll libraries make use of AMP.
So I downloaded: https://github.com/ageitgey/amplify
After I bundle, I get these messages:

```

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name (https://rubygems.org/gems/hitimes-1.2.2.gem)
Using colorator 0.1
Using ffi 1.9.10
Installing sass 3.4.15
Installing rb-fsevent 0.9.5
Using kramdown 1.9.0
Using liquid 3.0.6
Using mercenary 0.3.5
Using rouge 1.10.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Using bundler 1.11.2
An error occurred while installing hitimes (1.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install hitimes -v '1.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

```

After I installed hitimes, I got this message when attempting jekyll serve:

```

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Configuration file: /Users/mac/gits/jekyll/amplify/_config.yml
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/!
```

```
The weird thing is I DID install it with this command:

`gem install jekyll-paginate`

The _config.xml file contains:

`gems:
  - jekyll-paginate`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I will give you my step

1. `git clone https://github.com/ageitgey/amplify.git`
2. `cd amplify`
3. `bundle install`
4. `bundle update`
5. `bundle exec jekyll build --incremental`
6. `bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental -- watch`

do step by step above, now you get your Jekyll in AMP

Answer (score 0):

copy jekyll-paginate directory from ruby installation to _PLUGINS directory of your site.

or use this command to build and serve

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```